# Why changes applied to master branch though I did not merge

Tags: git, github

I was initially in master branch, then I create a `development` branch and use that branch by:

```
git branch development
git checkout development
```

After that, I start to make changes in my project on `development` branch.

Then, I commit and push :

`git push origin development` , so, I created a remote development branch.

Finally, I go back to `master` branch:

`git checkout master` ( **without merge** the changes made on `development` branch)

Then:

`git pull origin master`  (to get the other developers' changes on `master` branch)

**BUT, surprisingly**, all the changes on `development` branch are applied to `master` branch!! **WHY??**  I **did not** run command `git merge development` after I went back to `master` branch, why the changes applied to my `master` branch??

As it has already happens, how can I revert back my `master` branch to be **without** the changes from `development` branch now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in `git log`, I saw one developer did "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'" could that be the reason?

Yes, it is the reason, and your `git pull origin master` will:

- fetch the content of `origin/master` (which already contain the merge with `origin/development`)
- merge it with your local master branch (fast-forward merge)

Considering that `origin/master` has already been cloned around, I wouldn't advise changing its history at this point. So no '`git reset`'.

Should you *need* to go on working from a master before the merge, simply get the right SHA1 from `git log` and:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch right_SHA1
```

You would start a new branch from you last `master HEAD` before the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you edited untracked files or something?
Without more information it's hard to say.

Comment: That's all the information I have, I described every steps I did. What kind of more info do you need?

Comment: some kind of `git log` perhaps, im not sure.

Comment: if you clone a new repo, is the changes present in both branches?

Comment: Do you know how can I revert back my master branch which is my 2nd question

Comment: `git log` then `git reset --hard <sha1>` should do it?

Comment: in git log, I saw one developer did "Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'" could that be the reason? I mean some developer merged origin/developer to origin/master, as I have done "pull origin master" which makes the changes in development branch showing in master branch.